# How would I center a list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of href links that I want to center.

```html
<div id="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <style>
            ul li,
            ul li a {
                color:black;
                font-size:20px;
            }
        </style>
        <li><a href="Howdoesitwork%20Media.html">How Does it Work?</a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQ%20A%20Bug.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li ><a href="Discordserver.html">Discord Server</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So far I've tried

```html
<li style="text-align:center;><a href="Discordserver.html">Discord Server</a></li style="text-align:center;>
```

and

```html
<li><a style="text-align:center;href="Discordserver.html">Discord Server</a style="text-align:center;></li>`
```

Neither of these worked

Since there are three, is there a way of centering one of the lists and having one on the left and one on the right of the centered one?

Comment: Are you trying to center the entire list, or the individual list items?

Comment: @Nay917 Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the attached code, it will surely work. And if it doesn't let me know in the comments I will try my best to help you. I have added `margin-left: 50%;` corrected a bit of CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
        <style>
         li{
            color:black;
            font-size:20px;
            margin-left: 50%;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Howdoesitwork%20Media.html">How Does it Work?</a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQ%20A%20Bug.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li ><a href="Discordserver.html">Discord Server</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>`
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try
I think it will help

```
 .top-nav , ul { 
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve based on the question, but try this:

```css
ul {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Howdoesitwork%20Media.html">How Does it Work?</a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQ%20A%20Bug.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li ><a href="Discordserver.html">Discord Server</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I also want to note something else since you've said you're new to lists and maybe HTML – you don't need to apply inline styles to both the opening and closing tags, just the opening tags.

Incorrect:
`<li style="text-align:center;><a href="Discordserver.html">Discord Server</a></li style="text-align:center;>`

Correct:
`<li style="text-align:center;><a href="Discordserver.html">Discord Server</a></li>`

This won't actually cause any issues, but it's not valid HTML.